# Disable TLS/SSL check in Google App Engine - Java

Tags: java, windows, google-app-engine

My app is getting this error when accessing a HTTPS resource (using *appengine-java-sdk-1.9.63*):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not verify SSL certificate for URL: https://some.where/
        at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:175)
        at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:45)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:543)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:422)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getResponseCode(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:275)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:656)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:629)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:261)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:250)
```

What can be done so GAE would not check of SSL since in my current purpose for the app, it does not care if it connects via HTTP or HTTPS, so in my case I just want to disable SSL check.

**Update:**

I am running the application from Windows (Linux does not throw  the error above)

Already I have modifiied the *dev_appserver.cmd* like this:

```
java -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=false -cp "%~dp0\..\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar" ^
    com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart ^
       com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain %*
```

Also in the application itself this is set:

```
FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.doNotValidateCertificate();
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(getUrl, HTTPMethod.GET, fetchOptions)
```

What could be wrong with Windows that it throws the error whereas in Linux there is no problem?

Comment: So, in essence, you want your application to throw security out of the window? Disabling the SSL check means your application becomes vulnerable to both man-in-the-middle attacks and DNS hijacking attacks

Comment: Yes, as my app is not passing any credentials anyway, just need to fetch something from the URL, we could have just used HTTP, but the URL gets redirected to HTTPS.

Comment: HTTPS does more than simply "encrypt credentials", it's also a method to ensure authenticity: is the server I'm talking to really who they say they are. Now I'm not sure about the nature of the data you're fetching, but malformed data can be used as an attack vector, so I would recommend keeping SSL on and figuring out how to properly configure the endpoint instead (if it's one of your own servers check if the certificate is valid, if it's an external one run it through SSLLabs and contact the owners if errors pop up). Windows only error? Check if CA certificates are up-to-date on the machine

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke my app does not really fetch something that requires such need to check for credibility of the website, just need to get something from it and it returns something else my application will just ignore it, no credentials passed in between or anything.

Comment: Either way, you stated your problem does not occur on Linux. This leads me to suspect the Java install on the Windows instance is either out-of-date, or has outdated CA certificates.

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Yeah, that makes sense, it's been a while since we updated Java from that Windows server. Thanks for the tip, will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for this problem is to update the JDK of the machine. Then after upgrading from Java 7 to Java 8, the `SSLHandshakeException` is not being thrown anymore.

Thus, problem solved.